# Using variable for sheet name in excel VBA VLookup

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

```
Private Sub UpdateBoxes()
    Dim wsFunc As WorksheetFunction: Set wsFunc = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim sheet As String
    If Range("C1") = "some string" Then
        sheet = "SomeSheet"
    End If

    Range("B6").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("B7") 'Sets title of Box 1 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl
    Range("G6").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("C7") 'Sets title of Box 2 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl
    Range("B11").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("D7") 'Sets title of Box 3 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl
    Range("G11").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("E7") 'Sets title of Box 4 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl
    Range("B16").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("F7") 'Sets title of Box 5 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl
    Range("G16").Value = Sheets("Spreadsheet Ctrl").Range("G7") 'Sets title of Box 6 based on Spreadsheet Ctrl

    Range("C7").Value = wsFunc.VLookup(B6,'" & sheet & '"!A1:G5,3,)" 'Vlookup for "Current Revision
End Sub
```

The variable "sheet" will eventually change based on a nested if. It should then be passed to the last line of code before `End Sub`. I am getting a compile error that states "Expected: expression", and it highlights the first tick in `'" & sheet & '"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
Range("C7").Value = wsFunc.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("B6"), _
                                   Sheets(sheet).Range("A1:G5"),3,False)
```

Comment: `Range("C7").Value = wsFunc.VLookup(ActiveSheet.Range("B6"), Sheets(sheet).Range("A1:G5"), 3,) 'Vlookup for "Current Revision"` This reults in a compile error: "Expect: Expression" which highlights the last close parenthesis.

Comment: You're awesome. That did it. Thanks! ^_^ I didn't realize that was explicitly required since it isn't in the standard formula.